# ImageView sometimes load image successfully or not

Tags: c#

I want to bind some image on Winform image from uri. Sometimes it works but sometimes it does not works

[image.cs]

```
public void DownloadImage(Uri Uri)
    {            
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();            
        bi.CacheOption = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.UriSource = Uri;            

        bi.DownloadCompleted += Bi_DownloadCompleted;            
        bi.EndInit();     
    }

private void Bi_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi = (BitmapImage)sender;
        img.Source = bi;
```

}

[image.xaml.cs]

```
...

<Image Source ="{Binding bi}" Name="img"/>

...
```

After tag breakpoint under `bi.EndInit();` line, sometimes `bi.IsDownloading` property set true then it works `Bi_DownloadCompleted`, sometimes the property set false then also it does not works `Bi_DownloadCompleted`.

It also happened when I set same `url` on Url value.

Comment: It could be the image itself, or the server that it's on.  Can you give us an example Url?

Comment: It`s server one. I think you can get image link from any site.

Answer (score 0):

the Bi_DownloadCompleted is called in an async way. So, if you only set a breakpoint in the bi.EndInit() row, maybe the image is still downloading, so this is the reason why you see the IsDownloading property set to true or false.

Try to remove the bi.EndInit(); row in DownloadImage and set the following:

```
private void Bi_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage bi = (BitmapImage)sender;
    if (bi != null)
    {
        bi.EndInit();
        img.Source = bi;
    }
}
```

Comment: it still not works. Also, BitmapImage bi in method DownloadImage is not same on method Bi_DownloadCompleted one.